# How to make treeview fully support right-to-left (RTL) & display outer (UL) as bootstrap timeline

Tags: javascript, css, treeview, timeline

```js
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
    .tree, .tree ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
    .tree ul {
      margin-left:1em;
      position:relative
    }
    .tree ul ul {
      margin-left:.5em
    }
    .tree ul:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      border-left:1px solid
    }
    .tree li {
      margin:0;
      padding:0 1em;
      line-height:2em;
      color:#369;
      font-weight:700;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tree ul li:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:10px;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px solid;
      margin-top:-1px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1em;
      left:0
    }
    .tree ul li:last-child:before {
      background:#fff;
      height:auto;
      top:1em;
      bottom:0
    }
    .indicator {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .tree li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
    }
    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
      border:none;
      background:transparent;
      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .loading {
      font-style: italic;
    }
.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";

}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <ul id="tree2">
              <li>
                 <a href="#">TECH</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"> li text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> </li>                            <li>Report2 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>                              <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 XRP
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report2
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have this Treeview and I want to make it fully support right-to-left (RTL) display. I have already included a Bootstrap CSS link to support Arabic RTL, but it did not succeed in making it support right-to-left display. Note: I also want the outer ul elements (not the inner ones that appear when the Treeview is collapsed) to be included in a Bootstrap class called "timeline" and the outer ul elements should appear as shown in this image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```js
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
    .tree, .tree ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
      margin-right:10px;
    }
    .tree ul {
      margin-right:1em;
      position:relative
    }
    .tree ul ul {
      margin-right:.5em
    }
    .tree ul:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      border-right:1px solid
    }
    .tree li {
      margin:0;
      padding:0 1em;
      line-height:2em;
      color:#369;
      font-weight:700;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tree ul li:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:10px;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px solid;
      margin-top:-1px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1em;
      right:0
    }
    .tree ul li:last-child:before {
      background:#fff;
      height:auto;
      top:1em;
      bottom:0
    }
    .indicator {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .tree li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
    }
    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
      border:none;
      background:transparent;
      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .loading {
      font-style: italic;
    }
.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";

}
```

```html
    <div dir="rtl" class="row">
        <div  dir="rtl" class="col-md-4">
           <ul id="tree2">
              <li>
                 <a href="#">TECH</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"> li text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> </li>                            <li>Report2 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>                              <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 XRP
                 <ul>
                    <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                    <li>
                       Employees
                       <ul>
                          <li>
                             Reports
                             <ul>
                                <li>Report1 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report2
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                                <li>Report3 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
</li>
                             </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Human Resources</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```